# How to URL rewrite to another domain in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, url-rewriting

I have a React app with .NET Core back end hosted in a PaaS. I'm trying to URL rewrite a request to another application, but I'm not being able to rewrite it to another domain. For instance:

My application is located at:

`https://example.com`

My JS makes a GET request to /api/orders, then I have a request to:

`https://example.com/api/orders`

I'm trying to use the URL Rewrite middleware to rewrite this request to:

`https://another-example.com/api/orders`

I've already tried using this:

```
RewriteOptions rewriteOptions = new RewriteOptions()
    .AddRewrite(@"^api/orders/(.+)", "https://another-example/api/orders/$1", skipRemainingRules: true);
```

And also creating a class implementing the `IRule` interface, but none worked. These only work for same domain rewrites. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: did you get a chance to implement what you were looking for?

Comment: @PhaniKrishnaVemireddy i've ended up implementing my own middleware, simillar to what Andrea Chiarelli explains here https://auth0.com/blog/building-a-reverse-proxy-in-dot-net-core/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The middleware released with ASP.NET Core 2.x doesn't support Outbound Rules

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-3.0